Solving an inverse kinematics Equation to gain an intersection with a circle yields wrong results
I'm currently working on a computer graphics problem where I need to calculate 2 points on the edge of a circle based on another point in the circles interior. This interior point is a point along a ray / line that is closest to the circle's center. The 2 points on the circle's edge are the 2 intersection points of the ray with the circle. The information about the ray is not available for the calculation.
In more precise terms, the interior point was calculated using the standard "closest point" approach:
Given a ray $r$ with an origin at $r_o$ and a direction $r_d$ where
$r_o=\begin{pmatrix}
0.5 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ and
$r_d=\begin{pmatrix}
0.83205 \\
0.5547
\end{pmatrix}$
and a circle $c$ a position $c_p$ and a radius $c_r$ where
$c_p=\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
3.5
\end{pmatrix}$ and
$c_r=1.5$
The closest point $q$ to $c_p$ along $r$ was calculated via
$q=r_o + r_d*((c_p-r_o) \cdot r_d)$
where $*$ is multiplication and $\cdot$ is the dot product (for clarity). In this case this results in
$q=\begin{pmatrix}
4.76922 \\
3.84615
\end{pmatrix}$
The only information provided to solve the problem is $c_p$, $c_r$ and $q$. No information about the original ray $r$ generating $q$ is available. The goal is to calculate the intersection points of $r$ with $c$, named $p_1$ and $p_2$. Since $q$ is defined as the closest point to $c_p$ along a ray, there is only one possible solution for these two points, since there is only one possible ray that could have resulted in $q$.
To solve this problem I have been studying Inigo Quilez's article on a geometric solution to an Inverse Kinematics system: https://iquilezles.org/articles/simpleik/
The solution described in this article is based on two circles intersecting, but the second circle is only needed to determine the mid-point of the intersecting area $q$. The equation used to calculate the scalar $s$ should be applicable to the problem outlined above just as much. However, I am getting results that don't make any sense - here's my calculation:
$s=±\sqrt{c_r^2/\left| q \right|^2-1}$
The corresponding working GLSL code ($r = c_r$) from shadertoy (https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldlGR7) is:
float s = sqrt(r * r / dot(q, q) - 1.0);

Applied to above data:
$s=±\sqrt{2.25/37.53832-1}$
$s=±\sqrt{-0.94006125}$
$s=±0.969567558$
According to the GLSL implementation (which works perfectly in the demo), this $s$ is the multiplied onto a variation of $q$ and then added or subtracted from $q$ to get the points $p_1$ and $p_2$ (in this case):
return q + vec2(-q.y, q.x) * s;

This results in
$p_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1.04011 \\
8.47023
\end{pmatrix}$
$p_2=\begin{pmatrix}
8.49832 \\
-0.77793
\end{pmatrix}$
which both are not on the circle's edge. The article states that negative numbers in the square root during the calculation of $s$ signal that the two circles used for calculating $q$ are not overlapping. However, there has to be an overlapping circle implicitly defined by our point $q$, even if it wasn't calculated using a second circle. I must be missing something in this calculation, but I do not know what that is.
Is dot(q, q) in the GLSL code not equivalent to $\left| q \right|^2$ in the mathematical formula? And if not, why does it work in the shadertoy demo?
Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting a negative number as the radicand of the square root during the calculation of $s$? Am I wrong in my assumption, that an intersecting circle must be implied by the existence of our point $q$?

@hosamHajeer true, doesn‘t explain why this approach isn‘t working though, as it should be faster computationally.

The solution to the problem is, that the $q$ calculated in the article is based on a circle that is centered at the origin. The $q$ calculated as the closest point to the circle center along the ray does not move that circle to the origin. To make both results for $q$ equivalent, the ray-based result needs to have the position of the circle subtracted before use in the calculation of the scalar $s$.
